# Combining lists with similar elements in a matrix (Python)

Tags: python

I have this matrix

```
mat = [["a", 1], ["a", 0, 2], ["a", 0, 0, 3],\
       ["b", 1], ["b", 0, 2], ["b", 0, 0, 3],\
       ["c", 1], ["c", 0, 2], ["c", 0, 0, 3]]
```

I want to combine the lists that start with the same letter, so the desired output is

```
mat = [["a", 1, 2, 3],\
       ["b", 1, 2, 3],\
       ["c", 1, 2, 3]]
```

This might just be a simple problem and I'm just overthinking, but I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: what is `a`  - a string? a variable?

Comment: It is a string, I just edited the post to put the letters between quotation marks, thanks

Comment: Can we assume that all entries in the matrix always follow this pattern? Also do we know the dimensions of the matrix dont change?

Comment: All the entries follow this pattern, but some entries have more zeros before the number. This would make some entries longer than others, so the short ones get zeros afterwards so all lists end up with the same length

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
mat = [['a', 1], ['a', 0, 2], ['a', 0, 0, 3],\
       ['b', 1], ['b', 0, 2], ['b', 0, 0, 3],\
       ['c', 1], ['c', 0, 2], ['c', 0, 0, 3]]

output = []
for x,g in itertools.groupby(mat, lambda l:l[0]):
    t = list(x)
    for i,l in enumerate(g):
        t.append(l[i+1])
    output.append(t)
```

Output

```
[['a', 1, 2, 3], ['b', 1, 2, 3], ['c', 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the first element, assuming they are contiguous, you could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and then use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to iterate over all the lists in parallel:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mat = [['a', 1], ['a', 0, 2], ['a', 0, 0, 3],
       ['b', 1], ['b', 0, 2], ['b', 0, 0, 3],
       ['c', 1], ['c', 0, 2], ['c', 0, 0, 3]]


def reduce(group):
    _, *tail = zip_longest(*group, fillvalue=0)
    return [sum(e) for e in tail]


res = [[k, *reduce(group)] for k, group in groupby(mat, key=itemgetter(0))]
print(res)
```